# Linq join two objects to match customer selected records

Tags: c#, jquery, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have two List T objects. One is a list of forums available and the other the forums the user has selected. This is executing during a jquery ajax call and will be populating a listbox.

The purpose is that I want to flag the forums the user has subscribed to with "selected" which will of course render in the html listbox as a highlighted row.

I started to write this query and stopped short.

```
var result = (from exf in ExtForum
    join custfrm in customer.ExternalForums on
    exf.Id equals custfrm.Id
    select new { id=exf.Id, name=exf.ForumName, isSelected=(true ? "selected" : "")  })
    .ToList();
```

This will only return the forums that match. What I need is a left outer query but in thinking about that I don't think that is correct either. Well it is sort of correct as it would return all available forums but now I am back to square one of figuring out how I would flag my matches.

My approach which is open to improvement is to return basically a string object to jquery that then updates the html control.

```
ddlExtBoards.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name + " " + option.isSelected));
```

So advice / direction on what approach to accomplish this "match" would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The purpose is that I want to flag the forums the user has subscribed to with "selected"

A [left-join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) is what you want here, this means that all the records in `ExtForum` are included at least once and any other ones that match the join

```
var results = (from exf in ExtForum
               join custfrm in customer.ExternalForums on
               exf.Id equals custfrm.Id into customerForums
               from custForum in customerForums.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new 
               {
                   id = exf.Id,
                   name = exf.ForumName,
                   isSelected = custForum != null
               }
```

Comment: Ohhhh I see now how it is done. You dump the join into another object then match it up. SWEET!